# How to Import mongodb database from development Environment to local env by using Commmand?

Tags: mongodb

I have lots of collections in my development server. I need to use the same data for testing scenarios. I am trying to import all the data of development environment to local by command is it possible?

I successfully imported to a file by using below command:

```
mongoimport -d dbName -c collectionName dataFile.js
```

But how can we do same to import DB from development environment to local Env command-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mongoimport` tool is only intended for importing simple data in text formats (JSON, CSV, TSV).

To backup and restore a full database (including index definitions & collection options) typical approaches are to use either:

- [Filesystem snapshots](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-with-filesystem-snapshots/)
- [`mongodump` / `mongorestore`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-with-mongodump/)

The MongoDB manual has a section on [Backup and Recovery](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/backup/) describing supported approaches for different types of deployments (standalone, replica set, sharded cluster).